# About strict inequality in Groups Locally Nilpotent

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a locally nilpotent group and $x \in G$. How can I prove that $[G,x] \neq G$?

Note that if $G$ is a nilpotent group then this statement is true, because $G'=[G,G]<G$ and $[G,x]\leq G'$.
However, $G$ can be a locally nilpotent group such that $G=G'$ that this statement is still true.
How can I prove this?

Comment: Note that if $G$ is a nilpotent group then is true this affirmation, because $G'=[G,G] < G$ and $[G,x] \leq G'$. However, $G$ can be a locally nilpotent group such that $G = G'$ that this statement still worth. How can I prove this?

Comment: @AgenorAndrade, do you have an example of a locally nilpotent group $\;G\;$ such that $\;G'=G\;$ ?

Comment: I edited your first comment to your question. If you have something important to add, please edit your question. If you meant something other than what I wrote, feel free to edit again.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Thanks for editing my question. I really did not express myself very well in English.

Comment: @Timbuc There are a famous example of such groups, due to D.H. McLain, of locally nilpotent groups that are characteristically simple. These groups are perfect and have trivial center. The construction of such groups can be obtained for example in the book Derek Robinson "A Course in the Theory of Groups", chapter 12 (p.361/362).

Comment: @AgenorAndrade, thanks. That construction by McLain is one rather crazy animal.

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is nilpotent and has central series $1 <G_1 < \cdots < G_n=G$ and $x \in G_{i+1} \setminus G_i$ for some $i$, then $[G,x] \le G_i$, and so $x \not\in [G,x]$.

Now suppose that $G$ is locally nilpotent and $x \in [G,x]$. Then $x$ is a finite product of elements of the form $[g_i,x]^{\pm 1}$. But the finitely many $g_i$ in this product together with $x$ generate a nilpotent subgroup $H$ of $G$, and $x \in [H,x]$, contradicting what we proved above.

So $x \not\in [G,x]$ and $[G,x] \ne G$.